# Upper bound on quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, upper-lower-bounds

Say I have a quadratic form $x^\dagger H x$ with a hermitian matrix $H$ with $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and $H \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$. In other words $H = H^\dagger$ where $H^\dagger$ is the conjugate transpose of $H$ and so is $x^\dagger$ for the vector $x$. I know Rayleigh-Ritz principle guarantees an upper bound for the quadratic form $x^\dagger H x \le \lambda_{max} (H)$ where $\lambda_{max}$ is the largest eigenvalue in spectrum of $H$. Is there a different upper bound lower than $\lambda_{max}$ that exists for such quadratic forms ? If such a bound exists, a short simple proof for the same (or a literature discussing the proof) would be of great help . Note that in the problem spectrum of $H$ is finite.

Comment: Do you mean $H \in \Bbb C^{n \times n}$? Also, are we given the constraint that $\|x\| = 1$?

Comment: No, there is no better upper bound than $\lambda_{\max}$ since this upper bound is attained with $x$ equal to the associated eigenvector of $H$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben, yes I mean $||x|| =1$